# two list integer combine together in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get integers value from a list of specific functions in a two different list and then try to store both list integer with combination of 2nd list integer.
let suppose we have two list,

```
list1 = ['A(0)','B(1)','C(3)','Z(4)','Z(7)','Z(2)', 'X(3)','X(2)',...]
list2 = ['A(0)','B(1)','C(3)','Z(7)','Z(3)','Z(5)', 'X(11)','X(4)',...]
```

now only the integer of Z from list1 and list2 will extract and store like this sequence,

```
       Z1 = A(4,7)
       Z1 = A(7,3)
       Z2 = B(2,5)
```

first element of list1 and 2nd element of list2 in a sequence.

here is my code which i tried,

```py
    for line in list1:
      if 'OUTPUT' in line:
        print(line.split('Z(')[1].split(')')[0].strip())
```

```py
   for line in list2:
     if 'OUTPUT' in line:
        print(line.split('Z(')[1].split(')')[0].strip())
```

here is output

```
4 7 7 3 2 5
```

but still i didnt get value like,

```
    Z1 = A(4,7)
    Z1 = A(7,3)
    Z2 = B(2,5)
```

Comment: What is the order of the letters in `A(4, 7)`, `A(7, 3)`, and `B(2, 5)`?

Comment: first element of list one and 2nd element of list 2 in case A 4 is 1st element of list 1 and 7 is also first element of list 2

Comment: What about `X(3)`, `X(2)` and `X(11)`, `X(4)`? Are those not counted?

Comment: no need to count this one just elemente others

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand, but I posted a possible starting code below for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def format_list(lst):

    new = []
    for sub in lst:
        open_p = sub.index("(")
        close_p = sub.index(")")

        letter = sub[:open_p]
        number = sub[open_p + 1 : close_p]

        new.append((letter, number))

    return new

list1 = ["A(0)", "B(1)", "C(3)", "Z(4)", "Z(7)", "Z(2)", "X(3)", "X(2)"]
list2 = ["A(0)", "B(1)", "C(3)", "Z(7)", "Z(3)", "Z(5)", "X(11)", "X(4)"]

lst1 = format_list(list1)
lst2 = format_list(list2)
```

The above code will format the lists as so:

```
lst1 = [('A', '0'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '3'), ('Z', '4'), ('Z', '7'), ('Z', '2'), ('X', '3'), ('X', '2')]

lst2 = [('A', '0'), ('B', '1'), ('C', '3'), ('Z', '7'), ('Z', '3'), ('Z', '5'), ('X', '11'), ('X', '4')]
```

From there, you'll be able to use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to find the places in which the numbers differentiate:

```
different_obj = list(filter(lambda x: x[0][1] != x[1][1], zip(lst1, lst2)))
print(different_obj)
```

Or if you rather, you don't need to use `filter`:

```py
different_obj = []
for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if x[1] != y[1]:
        different_obj.append((x, y))
```

outputs:

```
[(('Z', '4'), ('Z', '7')),
 (('Z', '7'), ('Z', '3')),
 (('Z', '2'), ('Z', '5')),
 (('X', '3'), ('X', '11')),
 (('X', '2'), ('X', '4'))]
```

From there you should be able to organize `different_obj` to your goal.

Comment: also element x only display z values

Comment: I am sure you can figure that out from here. :)

Comment: Yup! Not a problem.